# Firebase: I want to update the metadata of files in storage after an administrator check

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm developing an image posting app that lets users post image files to firebase's cloud storage.

Map <String, String> type information can be written to the metadata of the image file.

So when the user posts an image, as metadata
{'displayability':'false'}
Is stored.

And after the administrator checks the posted image, the metadata of the image
{'displayability':'true'}
Update to.

And in the image list list display, I checked the metadata,
"{'Displayability':'true'}" as metadata
I want to show the user only the files that hold.

However, I'm not sure what to do specifically.

When I read documents etc., it means server side processing,

so I wonder if I will use cloud functions, but
If you have any hints, please teach me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no efficient way to "query" the images based on their metadata except for downloading them all then process it client side, which is not advisable in any case. Instead, I suggest you use a Firestore collection to keep track of which image has been approved by the admin. Each document should be something like this:

```
{
   "ref": "path/to/image",
   "displayability": true   //or false, depends on whether the image has been approved
   //You can add any additional info here, like upload time, uploader's name, etc...
}
```

Then you can make a simple query to Firestore to get a list of approved images, then download them from Cloud Storage. And when you need to get list of unapproved images, the process is basically the same. This solution doesn't require any Cloud Functions code at all.

Comment: I would like to think in that direction.

I have no idea about best practices such as Firestore data design, where can I get information close to best practices?

Comment: @森口万太郎 You can watch this video series from Firebase https://www.youtube.com/c/firebase/playlists . It's really good

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called "updataMetadata(SettableMetadata metadata)".

just pass the updated metadata using above function.